# Using `try` in `if` loop?

Tags: python, webdriver

I am still learning python. Its week 2 for me.

I am trying to webscrape with webdriver and python:

The site(s), have a few changing `elements` which are similar for a few and then change for the rest/few.

To handle this I thought of the following(docs helped):

```
try:
    e = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="html_job"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span[2]').text
    if e != str:
        try:
            e = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="html_job"]/body/div[7]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span[2]').text
            if e != str:
                print("No Landline found" + url)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Elements not present, setting value")
            e = 'There is no landline'
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Out of try")
```

Output:

> Out of try

I understand that the first `try` doesn't find the element and throws the exception leading to the output.

I am trying to figure out what would be the proper way to go about this?

Comment: try to print exception you will get to know where you are going wrong.            try this                                                                                                           except NoSuchElementException as e:print(e)

Comment: @REHANSHIKKALGAR I know that the element doesn't exist on some pages. So basically I want it to check whether element is present or not. Can't keep checking as number of pages is too high.

Comment: `find_element` appears to be raising the exception; `if e != str` never executes, because control transfers immediately to the `except` clause. What do you actually *want* to do in that case?

Comment: Go to the next `try`. Wait I have a new idea, if I add the next try in the `except` of the first it should work?

Comment: Got it to work!! It might not be the best way, but works for now. Not sure if I should post it as an answer or just edit the question and attach the answer.